JWT Token expiration does not bring user back to /login page
I am working on a PERN project with JWT Token for authorization. Currently, I've faced this issue where the user with an expired JWT token will stay on the same page, with a toast error message stating that 'ERROR in Authorization: Token expired'.
I want my user to be redirected to /partner/login with local storage cleared and toast message shown if an expired token is detected.
However, in my case, FE knows that the JWT token is already expired since console.log('expiredddddd') is printed but the sequence lines are not functioning since toast message is not shown, localStorage is not clear, user was not redirected to a /partner/login. The user has to do a manual page refresh to get redirected to /partner/login. Anyone can help to look into this issue?
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Spinner from "../utils/Spinner";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({
  isAuthenticated,
  loading,
  isLoggingOut, // New prop to indicate if the user is logging out
}) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if token exists and is not expired
    if (token) {
      const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
      const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // Convert milliseconds to seconds
      if (decodedToken.exp < currentTime) {
        // Token expired
        console.log("expiredddddd"); // this was printed but sequence lines got ignored 
        toast.error("Your session has expired. Please log in again.");
        localStorage.clear(); // Remove expired token
        return <Navigate to="/partner/login" />;
      }
    }
  }, [token]);

  // Check if there is no token and the user is not authenticated
  if (!token && !isAuthenticated && !isLoggingOut) {
    toast.error("You have not logged in");
    return <Navigate to="/partner/login" />;
  }

  // Check if the user is not authenticated and loading is complete
  if (!isAuthenticated && !loading && !isLoggingOut) {
    toast.error("You have not logged in");
    return <Navigate to="/partner/login" />;
  }

  // Show loading spinner while authentication status is being determined
  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  // Render the child routes if the user is authenticated
  return <Outlet />;
};

export default AuthenticatedRoute;

this is my middleware
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  // get token and method from header
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (authHeader) {
    // Split the authorization header into parts
    const parts = authHeader.split(" ");
    if (parts.length === 2 && parts[0] === "Bearer") {
      const jwtToken = parts[1]; // Extract the token from the header
      try {
        const payload = jwt.verify(jwtToken, process.env.jwtSecret);
        req.user = payload.user; // Attach user data to request object

        next();
      } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof jwt.TokenExpiredError) { 
          return res
            .status(401)
            .json({ error: "ERROR in Authorization: Token expired" }); 
                   // I was able to see this message
        } else if (err instanceof jwt.JsonWebTokenError)
          return res
            .status(401)
            .json({ error: "ERROR in Authorization: Invalid JWT" });
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ error: "ERROR in Authorization: Server error" });
      }
    } else {
      // Invalid authorization header format
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid authorization header" });
    }
  } else {
    // Authorization header not present
   return res.status(401).json({ error: "Authorization header missing" });
  }
};

